# How to acess argument from a function passed as argument in SML

Tags: arguments, sml, mosml

I am new to coding SML and am still trying to understand pattern matching. I am trying to find out how to access an argument from a function passed as an argument in SML. For example, if a function takes 2 arguments, a function and an integer, how can I access the argument (for simplicity, assuming it only has one) that the argument function has. Does this question even make sense in SML? Here is some code, which doesn't work, but I think it illustrates what I am trying to do.

```
fun argumentExtraction (n,f) =
    case f of
        fn x => x
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to do introspection of the sort which is possible in Python (where you *can* get information about the arguments of a function when you are passed that function). That isn't possible in SML. It would be hard to implement with static typing. What are you hoping to do?

Comment: I think you understood what I was trying to do properly, but I guess it doesn't work in SML. My goal is to find a way to execute the function, fn, in my code example on the argument it takes, which apparently I can't access directly.

Comment: @JohnJenkins Just to clarify: What Python can do is tell you how many arguments a function takes and what their names are. It does not tell you the actual value that you should pass to the function. That value is really for you to decide in any language.

Answer (score 1):

A function doesn't *have* arguments, it *takes* arguments. You give arguments to the function and you get a result back. You can't ask the function what its arguments are because it doesn't have them yet. You are supposed to give the arguments to the function.

---

To make this perhaps a bit clearer, let us consider an example. Let's take the following functions:

```
fun add x y = x + y
fun plus1 x = x + 1

fun applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

Now `applyTwice` takes a function and an argument and applies the function to the argument twice. We can call it like this:

```
applyTwice plus1 40
```

or like this:

```
applyTwice (add 1) 40
```

and in both cases the answer is going to be 42 (because that's the value of `plus1 (plus1 40)` and of `add 1 (add 1 40)`, `add 1` really being the exact same function as `plus1`).

Now I'm not sure whether you want to be able to pass `(plus1 40)` as the value for `f` and then somehow get `40` from that or whether you want to pass `(add 1)` and then somehow get back the `1`, but both are impossible.

In the case of `(plus1 40)` you can't even pass that as the value for `f`. `f` is supposed to be a function, but `(plus1 40)` is an integer (41), not a function.

`(add 1)` on the other hand is a function and you can indeed pass it as the value for `f`. In fact I did so in my example. But what you can't do is get the value `1` back from it. I mean, imagine there was a way that you could do that. What should then happen if you passed `plus1` instead of `(add 1)`. What should you get back from that? There is no value captured in `plus1`, so there's really nothing to get back, but clearly `plus1` is just as valid an argument to `applyTwice` as `(add 1)`.

The only way this could possibly make sense is if partially applied function had a different type from normal functions, allowing you to define a function that accepts `(add 1)` as one argument, but not `plus1`. However that's not the case ML and there's really not much benefit to that. Having different types of functions would just make the type system more complicated and make it more difficult to define higher order functions (as they'd have to be able to deal with both types of function). Nor do I see the use case where this ability would even be helpful.

Comment: So it doesn't make sense in SML to pass a function that has an argument as an argument? Would that mean the closest alternative to accessing a function argument's argument would be having the function take an additional argument representing that argument (separating it from the function it takes)?

Comment: @JohnJenkins I'm not sure what you mean by the first part. If you're talking about partially applying a curried function: It does often make sense to do that, but you can't get the partially applied argument back from it - it's just a captured variable and only a function itself can access its captured variables. There's no way to tell whether the function you're taking as an argument captured any variables, let alone to access them. For your second question: Yes, if you need the argument, that's the way to do it.

Comment: So you can't access them directly, but is there a way to apply the function to them, assuming the function is passed with that argument? Apparently the function that takes a function as an argument wouldn't be able to access that function's argument, but if it can access the function it is passed and that function can access its argument does that work?

Comment: @JohnJenkins A function can be applied to an argument. It doesn't matter where that argument comes from. If you want to take an `int -> int` function as an argument, you could write `fun foo (f: int -> int) = f 42` or you could write `fun foo (f: int -> int) (x: int) = f x` or even `fun foo (f: int -> int) (g: int -> int) (x: int) = f (g x)`. That is: it does not matter whether the argument was passed as an argument to your function, whether it's a constant or the result of another function. You just take any value of the correct type and call the function with it.

Comment: @JohnJenkins Please see the update to my answer. Maybe this makes it clearer what you can and can't do (or at least makes it clearer what I didn't understand about your question, so you can clarify, so I understand what you're trying to achieve).